# Django REST API and web interface on the same server...where to put things?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I have this problem: I have to build a server that provides a REST API for partners, but also provides a web interface to the same functionality. Basically there are two servers that provide two different interfaces for the same thing, one of which is also providing REST API (let's call it **server1**) for the other (let's call it **server2**). I am having problems figuring out where to put the code that handles the functionality. In my oppinion i have the following options, out of which none are satisfying:

- It seems funky for **server1** to serve a web interface that uses the REST API. Although I am not sure this is not correct, to me it seems weird to have a view providing a page that calls REST endpoints on the same server (including authentication)
- If I put it in the views, it means I would have to beak DRY at some level. Even if I call some library, it would be the same functionality getting called from two places.
- I would go for adding it in the models (basically overriding the save method), but this obviously breaks the MVC-don't add logic to models rule. Plus, it's a bit clunky to implement a high-level functionality at such a low level.

So, any ideas? Thanks!

PS: I am using django-rest-framework for the REST API...(if that matters)

Comment: WHy not just serve everything from same server - just serve those things from different addresses? Or why not use the same rest api for your own web interface?

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb as I stated in my first idea, it seems a bit odd to authenticate via OAuth2 on the same server...I don't know how people are usually doing this, but I doubt they are calling REST endpoints from pages served by the same server... As for serving everything from the same server, well, it's impossible since this is how the project is defined

Comment: Why is it impossible? Your site can use exactly the same rest api - just use stuff like backbone or angular to create templated ui.

Comment: I did not say it is impossible. To me it seems weird and I was wondering if there is a better way. I am sure I am not the only one doing this kind of things and am just wondering how is everybody else doing it. Until now I've been implementing these functionalities in the models' save methods, it works great, just that it's not correct.